# Отправка сообщения при старте бота на python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Нужно сделать так, чтобы бот выдавал сообщение в чат (например: бот онлайн), при каждом его запуске с машины.
Мой код (выдается ошибка при запуске):

```
import logging
import os, json, string
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
#import ReplykeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#bot init
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot) 

#сообщение при старте бота 
async def on_startup(_):
    await message.answer('Я онлайн!')

#/help
async def cmd_test2(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('<b>Привет, {0}! Я официальный бот твоего любимого чата.</b>\n\
Пока я ничего не умею, но вскоре всему научусь!'.format(message.from_user.first_name),parse_mode="html")

dp.register_message_handler(cmd_test2, commands="helpWiedzmin")

#фильтры текста 
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if "рыжий" in message.text.lower(): 
        await message.reply('!варн')
        await message.delete()
    if {i.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for i in message.text.split(' ')}\
        .intersection(set(json.load(open('who.json')))) != set():
        await message.reply('А кто это??')

# run long-polling
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функции on_startup(_) не объявлена переменная message, на которую бот мог бы ответить методом answer. Вместо этого нужно отправить сообщение методом bot.send_message(), где chat_id - id нужного чата:

```
async def on_startup(_):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Сообщение")
```

Comment: К сожалению, выдает огромную ошибку

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Bott\bot.py", line 36, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 320, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
   Многое сюда не влезает, так что отправлю частями

Comment: File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\executor.py", line 377, in _startup_polling
    await callback(self.dispatcher)
  File "C:\Bott\bot.py", line 15, in on_startup
    await bot.send_message(1736429778, "Сообщение")
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 339, in send_message

Comment: result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())

Comment: File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 121, in check_result
    exceptions.Unauthorized.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantInitiateConversation: Forbidden: bot can't initiate conversation with a user

Comment: "Бот не может начинать беседу с пользователем" - если в chat_id вы указали чат с пользователем, то он должен разрешить боту писать ему сообщения

Comment: Если вы отправляете сообщение в группу, то у бота должен быть в ней доступ к сообщениям. Так же следует заметить, что id чатов в группах начинаются с минуса

Comment: Бот писать может, все разрешения у него есть. С минусом попробовал - не помогло. Но все равно большое спасибо

Comment: Возможно, вы указали неверный ID чата. Попробуйте добавить в начало функции filter_message строку
    print(message.chat.id)
 , на время убрать из вызова функции executor.start_polling() аргумент on_startup, запустить бота, написать что-то в нужный чат, заменить в вашей функции on_startup() id чата на тот, что вывело.
После чего вернуть аргумент on_startup и снова запустить бота.

Comment: Все заработало! Огромное спасибо. Я брал айди с бота "Get My ID", но видимо что-то пошло не так

Comment: А есть ли возможность делать то же самое, только при выключении бота?

Comment: Да - у функции start_polling() есть аргумент on_shutdown.

Comment: Хотя, кажется, это не будет работать в том виде, в котором вам нужно